# How to apply time and isRead both filter in receive mail graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I've use this
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?filter=(receivedDateTime gt 2023-01-24T10:47:27.168Z)&isRead+ne+true`
and this API return based only date filter not based on both.

**I want to get mail bt applying both filter[Date and isRead]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do agree with @user2250152, you can also use `not` operator with `eq` operator:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?filter=receivedDateTime gt 2023-01-20T10:47:27.168Z and not(isRead eq true)
```

[image]

**References taken from:**

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/filter-query-parameter?tabs=http

Comment: **Both answer is Right**
Thanks @RithwikBojja

Answer (score 0):

Use `and` conditional operator in `$filter` query to define the second condition.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?filter=receivedDateTime gt 2023-01-20T10:47:27.168Z and isRead ne true
```